# Using-declaration to move name to another namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, using-declaration

Given:

```
namespace One {
  void foo(int x) {
    munch(x + 1);
  }
};

namespace Two {
  // ... see later
}

...
void somewhere() {
  using namespace Two;
  foo(42);
  ...
```

is there any difference between the following two variants:

a)

```
namespace Two {
  void foo(int x) {
    munch(x + 1);
  }
};
```

and b)

```
namespace Two {
  using One::foo;
};
```

EDIT: It's pretty clear that (a) duplicates the code which should never be a good idea. The question is more about overload resolution etc. ... what if there are other `foo`s or `munch`es in possibly other namespaces?

Comment: "using One::foo;" is called a using-declaration; a using-directive is "using namespace N;".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a, they are actually different functions, but with b, the two functions are identical:

```
assert(&One::foo == &Two::foo);
```

This would rarely matter; a bigger concern is duplicating the logic.

Answer (score 0):

As for the usage they are equivalent. As for code, in case a) you're duplicating the function `foo()` code. That is, both versions will make available the `foo()` function inside `Two`, but the a) case generates the code for `foo` twice, because the compiler doesn't have any hint in discovering it is the same function.